# Django: my Form isn't persisting on database

Tags: python, django, database, forms, persistence

I have here the following structure:

`models.py:`

```
class MyUser (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=255, required=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_lenght=255, required=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_lenght=255, required=True)
    company = models.CharField(max_lenght=255,required=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="client")
    @property
    def email(self):
       return self.user.email
```

`forms.py:`

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class MyUserForm(forms.Form):
    name= forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    pass = forms.CharField(required=True)
    phone = forms.CharField(required=True)
    company = forms.CharField(required=True)
    def is_valid(self):
        valid = True
        if not super(MyUserForm, self).is_valid():
            self.adiciona_erro('Error. Pleas correct the form.')
            valid = False
        user_exists = User.objects.filter(username=self.data['name']).exists()
        if user_exists:
            self.adiciona_erro('User already exists.')
            valid = False
        return valid
   def adiciona_erro(self, message):
        errors = self._errors.setdefault(forms.forms.NON_FIELD_ERRORS, forms.utils.ErrorList())
        errors.append(message)
```

And the `views.py`:

```
class MyUserView(View):

    def get(self, request):
       return render(request, self.template_name)

    def post(self, request):

        form = MyUserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            dados_form = form.data

            user = User.objects.create_user(dados_form['name'], dados_form['email'], dados_form['pass'])            

            client = Client(name=dados_form['name'], 
                            email=dados_form['email'], 
                            phone=dados_form['phone'],
                            nome_empresa=dados_form['company'],
                            user=user)

            ###########################################
            #SHOULD SAVE ON DATABASE, NO?
            client.save()
            ###########################################

            return redirect('index')

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form' : form})
```

Everything works, except save on database. I need to use the Form class because I want personalize my web page.
Why does it not save in the DB?

I'm using postgree.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you get any errors? also you should use `dados_form = form.cleaned_data`

Comment: Please show the `Client` model.

Comment: Why `client = Client(…)` + `client.save()` instead of `Client.objects.create(…)`? Also, if you could use `ModelForm` instead of `Form`, you could remove the `User` creation code.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shouldn't override `is_valid()` in your form. You should override either a `clean_<fieldname>` method (e.g. `clean_name`) or `clean` instead. See the [docs on form validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) for more info. Your `adiciona_erro` method looks unnecessary. Just raise `ValidationError`, or call [`add_error`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.add_error)

Secondly, if the form is valid, you should access the values from `form.cleaned_data` instead of `form.data`.

If you're still stuck after making those changes, you need to add more information about what isn't working. Is the `post` method being called? Is `form.is_valid()` returning `True` or `False`. If it's `False`, what are the form errors?